# Open set between two curves

Tags: general-topology

Let $U := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 > y \} \;\cap\; \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \geq 0 \}$.

I want to prove (!) that $U$ is an open set. Therefore I made a sketch:

[image: Open set between two parabels]

Here $U$ is represented by the blue area.
The basic idea I had for the proof was to show that $U$ can be described as an infinite union of open spheres around all real points on the $x$-axis with $x > 0$.

I've tried and  have come to the conclusion that there **must be an easier way** to prove this as it was part of an exam in my university.

**EDIT**

As stated in the comments, the **sketch of $U$ above is wrong** as e.g. $(0, -1) \in U$. It should rather look like this:

[image: Correct sketch of set U]

And then it is obvious that $U$ **cannot be open** as there is no open surrounding of $(0, -1)$ which is a subset of $U$.

Comment: I have some doubt here…is (0,-1) in U and if it is…is it an interior point?

Comment: Sorry, your approach, while I can't say if it easier of course, but I agree should prove the result, contrary to what I said earlier.

Comment: @Li Chun Min Well, I think you are right, something is wrong with the sketch.

Comment: Maybe show there is no $x$ or $y$ max or min?

Comment: @marshalcraft Consider the set $[0, 1] \cup [-2, -1] \cup [2, 3] \cup [-4, -3] \cup \dots$. It has no min and no max but it is yet not open.

Comment: Or use the balls with radius $\sqrt y$ to show for any $x$ you can construct an open ball which in $U$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easier to see that

$$U = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 > y \} \;\cap\; \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x > 0 \}$$

And $A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 > y \}$ is open, beacuse $f(x,y) = x^2-y$ is continuous, and $A = f^{-1} (]0,+\infty[)$, hence the inverse image of an open set y a continuous function.

Same with $B = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x > 0 \}$, by considering $g(x,y) = x$ that is also continuous.

And the intersection of two open sets is also an open set

Comment: yeah…we shall have x strictly greater than 0…

Comment: To me it is not clear at all in words what statement you are trying to make about $g$ and the set $B$. Yes $B$ is open. $g$ is boundary, continuous. Now what?